# Magento 2: MassAction Model LSD method delete()

Tags: magento2, massaction, coding-standards

My massaction functionalities are working fine.
According to CodingStandard it shows this warning.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 38 | WARNING | Model LSD method delete() detected in loop
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have attached my MassDelete code below.

```
<?php

namespace modulename\Wallet\Controller\Adminhtml\Transaction;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use modulename\Wallet\Model\ResourceModel\Transaction\CollectionFactory;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_filter = $filter;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('transaction_id', ['in' => $data]);
        $recordDeleted = 0;
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $auctionProduct) {
            $auctionProduct->setId($auctionProduct->getId());
            $auctionProduct->delete();
            $recordDeleted++;
        }
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $recordDeleted)
        );

        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT)->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LSD comes from `load/save/delete`. You should not call these methods inside loops.
But in this case, if you want to hide the dirt under the rug you can crete a new method in your class

```
private function deleteItem($item)
{
    $item->delete();
}
```

and replace the line `$auctionProduct->delete();` with

```
$this->deleteItem($auctionProduct);
```

and the code sniffer will stop complaining.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works, mark the answer as accepted in order to help future readers.

Comment: in your post please edit this line $this-deleteItem($auctionProduct); u have missed $this->

Comment: Done. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

If hiding the LSD delete method behind the `private` visibility domain doesn't impress PHPCS you may try calling your method inside an `array_walk` loop instead of foreach. From what I know `array_walk` is less performant than `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

- You're using the delete() method inside a loop which in not recommended and has to be avoided.

Comment: ok. Thanks. Do you know any alternative method for this ?

Comment: I have done like this only.. but it shows warning.