# How to resolve "Model LSD method save() detected in loop" in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, model, save

I am getting a warning as a
"Model LSD method save() detected in the loop" when I did MEOP2"

The issue is on below the line

> $model->setData($finalData)->save();

Please anyone can help me to resolve this issue

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSD comes from load/save/delete as Marius says in his answer here: [Magento 2: MassAction Model LSD method delete()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212694/magento-2-massaction-model-lsd-method-delete)

Try to avoid saving data inside a loop

Comment: Hi @SantiBM Thank you,It's working for me.

Comment: Great! mark the answer as correct if it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid save function inside the loop.

Try the below code

```
private function saveItem($model, $finalData)
{
    $model->setData($finalData)->save();
}
```

and replace the line **$model->setData($finalData)->save();** with

```
$this->saveItem($model, $finalData);
```